# "laravel new blog" shows PHP version too low

Tags: php, laravel

There are multiple PHP versions in my PC. I want to use PHP 5.6.27 to create a new project named "blog". I use "laravel new blog" but it shows these errors:

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.5.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.5.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.1 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.1].
    - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.1 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.27) does not satisfy that requirement
```

Comment: laravel 5.5 needs php 7.0 to get installed, without that you cannot user laravel 5.5

Comment: so,use "laravel new blog" how can i controll use which php version and laravel version?

Comment: laravel new blog --version